# HI does anyone know why this isn't working properly? HTML JS program currency converter

Tags: javascript, html

when i run it it doesnt work so im not sure what the issue is thanks in advance. Im not sure if its a .value issue but the header wont update so maybe thats wrong too

html code

```
  <html>
    <header>
     <title>
     Currency converter
    </title>
    <h3>  Welcome to the currency converter!</h5>
    </header>
    
    <body>
    
      <input id ="numberInput" type="number" >
    
      <button id ="button" onclick="euroToUs()">Click me</button>
    
      <p id ="result">Converted amount = </p>
      <h1 id ="hi"> hi </h1>
    
    
    
    </body>
    <script src ="currencyConverter.js"></script>
    
    </html>
```

js code

```
//euro to usd
function euroToUs(x){
  let x = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;
  let convertedNumber = (x * .97);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = convertedNumber;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work." Does nothing happen? Is there an error in the console? Does it do something unexpected?

Comment: basically when I open the live server i input the number and nothing happens to the result section like it doesnt get updated

Comment: The problem is with the `x` parameter you have defined in `function euroToUs(x)`, just remove the parameter and it should work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `x` in `function euroToUs(x)` is not in use. Get rid of it. It seems that the error occurs because the `let x` is the same identifier as the argument `x`.

```js
function euroToUs() { // Get rid of x
  let x = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;
  let convertedNumber = (x * .97);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = convertedNumber;
}
```

Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKED!! and your explanation actually helped me understand the idea behind it !

Comment: Glad it worked out. I recommend you check errors on Console. It helps a lot in understanding what is going on.